# how to get last few numbers of an element in an array?

Tags: ruby

array = [13845, 23424, 89021, 83628]

How would I return the last 2 numbers of each element?

expected output:
45
24
21
28

I have tried array[i].to_s.last(2) but I received the error message: "undefined method `last' for "13845":String"

Answer (score 6):

Just use `array.map` in Ruby. `String::last` isn't standard Ruby and part of Rails ActiveSupport.

```
array.map { |e| e % 100 }
```

Comment: Does not work on negative numbers. Maybe `abs` first.

Answer (score 2):

`array.map { |i| i.to_s[-2..-1] }` will do it in non-Rails Ruby, but CherryDT's handling of the elements as numbers is cleaner.

EDIT: It looks like CherryDT's answer has been removed, but
Armin Primadi does the same thing, and that is the better answer. I only offer this because of your attempt to use `.to_s`.